Decidability of Turing Machine
The problem is:

Argue, whether it is decidable if a Turing machine M halts within 10 steps on any input.

The proposed solution:

Simulate every input of length less than or equal to 10 on M. If M halts on any of these inputs within 10 steps, it does so for all inputs, since M can only read one input letter per step

I do not think this is a correct solution, although it is proposed by my uni. IMO checking all inputs of length 10 and less does not allow to infer that M does or does not halt on any input bigger than 10.

It is correct. What is your question?

@NaïmFavier  I think the following sentence "checking all inputs of length 10 and less does not allow to infer that M does or does not halt on any input bigger than 10" makes it obvious to what the asker wants to be clarified.

When a machine performs at most 10 steps, then it can reach at most 10 tape-cells. In particular, the tape's content that lies right to the 10'th tape cell does not affect that machine's computation. Hence,
a machine halts on an input $x = \sigma_1\cdot \sigma_2 \cdots \sigma_k$ of length $k\geq 11$ within at most 10 steps only when it halts on its prefix $\sigma_1\cdot \sigma_2\cdots \sigma_{10}$ within at most 10 steps.
